# concat a DataFrame with a Series in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Can someone explain what is wrong with this pandas concat code, and why data frame remains empty ?I am using anaconda distibution, and as far as I remember it was working before.
[image]

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You want to use this form:

```
result = pd.concat([dataframe, series], axis=1)
```

The `pd.concat(...)` doesn't happen "inplace" into the original `dataframe` but it would ***return*** the concatenated result so you'll want to assign the concatenation somewhere, e.g.:

```
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> s = pd.Series([1,2,3])
>>> df = pd.DataFrame()
>>> df = pd.concat([df, s], axis=1)  # We assign the result back into df
>>> df
   0
0  1
1  2
2  3
```